# Using setWhatIsThis in Qt with QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

I need to show a "help text" when the mouse is over a pushbutton, I googled and I tried some code but in vain.

Can anyone correct it to me?

```
if (event->type() == QEvent::Enter)
{
    if (obj == q1)
    {
        iarm->printStatus("hi"); // For debugging
        QAction *newAct = new QAction(tr("&New"), this);
        newAct->setShortcut(tr("Ctrl+N"));
        newAct->setStatusTip(tr("Create a new file"));
        newAct->setWhatsThis(tr("Click this option to create a new file."));
    }
}
```

Comment: how about a [tooltip](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop)?

Comment: tool did not give me smart text but it may be the solution

Comment: what do you mean "smart text"?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going via the QAction, just use your QPushButton's (well, QWidget's really) [`setToolTip(const QString &)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop).

That will set a tooltip for your button/widget which appears when your mouse hovers over it. It seems that is what you're going for, rather than the "What's This" message you're trying to use now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QpushButton's property setToolTip ( const QString & ) for the same.
This will display your help text on mouse hovering over Qpushbutton.

For Smart text as per your requirement you can set stylesheet for Tooltip:-

QToolTip { color: #fff; background-color: #000; border: none; }